# different number of wires

Tags: wiring

Trying to wire new cooktop.  There are 4 wires coming from the house - red. black, white and bare copper.  From the new cooktop, there are 3 wires - red, black and green.  What hooks up to what?  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Since your. Cook top looks to only use 240v. You won't need the neutral I would cap it with a wire nut or cover it with tape, the green is the grounding wire it connects to the bare copper. Next the blacks go to black and red to red these 2 wires are each 120v to neutral/ ground but 240v black to red. Thanks I read it 2x then answered thinking of 2 blacks updated . but black to red swap would also work but won't look right.

Comment: You might read the question a bit more carefully. Neither connection has two blacks. Red to red, black to black, bare to green, cap the white, done.

Comment: Thanks I was think red/black won't matter and 4 wire black black feed but updated.